# Why does Lord Krishna wear peacock feather on His head?

Tags: krishna, symbolism

- Why does Lord Krishna wear peacock feather on His head?
- What is the significance of playing Basuri/Flute by Lord Krishna?
- Is there any reference that took place that made Lord Krishna to wear peacock feather on His head and Flute in His hand respectively?

[image]

Comment: Flute symbolizes the ultimate servant. The flute does absolutely nothing. it just allows the Lord to blow the wind through it, thereby producing music. Similarly the example of the flute is that we as human beings should allow the Lord to speak through us, to walk through us, the act through us, to think through us. Then a beautiful music of Sri Krishna will be produced by Him. All the best!!

Comment: The plume on Shri Krishna's crown is a mirror to many hard core realities exemplified through the feather. We all know that peacock is known for its beautiful multi-colored feathers. These feathers were used in decorative forms by the rural people in old days. Shri Krishna wore it to make it popular and at the same time to be accepted by the common masses.

Answer (score 2):

The flute is symbolic of the spine which has apertures. On activation of all the chakras, the vayu blows through this spine in the sukshma sharira and enables the tapasvi to do sattvic karmas and other high class siddhis. Swami Sivananda had written that on reaching closer to the inner divine a tapasvi hears the sound of the flute and bell inside his head. (not like a hallucination).

Peacock feathers have crystals which enhance the powers of the pineal gland which too have similar crystals. The colours of the peacock feather are the same as that of the sun seen in NASA photos, and the surya bija mantra '”Om Hraam Hreem Hraum Sah Suryay Namah” activates shaktis as described in Ram and Krushna Leelas. Peacock is also vahan of Kartikeya who is metaphorical 'son' of Siva, or the divine powers produced by meditation on Siva.

Comment: That’s great, thx for posting this comment ! 

Answer (score 1):

It signifies Lord's **askalitha brahmacharitva** (means perfect/eternal celibate). 
Lord wears it to signify that his a ajanma brahmachari/nitya brahmachari. It is proven when Lord revives the foetus of the womb of uttara.(who is none other than maharaja parikshit son of abhimanyu).

Peacock is the only species which doesn't reproduce through the samyoga of male and female reproductory organs, the peahen collects tears of peacock(which contain reproduction cells) and lay eggs.

If we dwell deep in to it, we can understand the eternal relationship of Lord with Gopis and his 16108 wives.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Its wrong assumption what others say. https://www.quora.com/Epics-of-India-Is-it-true-that-peacocks-dont-mate-physically

Comment: @KIRAN KUMAR please read this https://sciencing.com/peacocks-mate-4565678.html

Answer (score 1):

Excerpts from talks by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar:

> ...Why does Krishna have the peacock feather on his head? A king is
>   responsible for the whole society and that responsibility can become a
>   burden, which sits on the head as the crown. But Krishna fulfills all
>   his responsibility effortlessly, like a game. A mother never feels
>   taking care of her children is a burden. Similarly, Krishna wears his
>   responsibility lightly and plays his roles colorfully, just like the
>   peacock feather on his crown.

http://srisriravishankar.org/the-deeper-meaning-of-janamashtami/

> ...In the presence of pure bliss, joy, all complaints vanish and life
>   appears like a play. One can look at every trouble as a challenge or
>   can spend it crying and complaining. You know, what you have in your
>   hand indicates what you are inside. If you have a gun in your hand, it
>   indicates fear or violence. If you have a flower in your hand, it
>   indicates you are like a flower. If you have a flute in your hand, you
>   are like a flute — hollow and empty.

http://talksbysrisriravishankar.blogspot.in/2013/04/the-philosophy-of-joy-talk-by-sri-sri.html