# Is Shanti Parva an interpolation in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, darshan, interpolation

In the [translation of Mahabharata](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/index.htm) by K. M. Ganguli, we see a paragraph note in the page which states:

> The Santi Parva is a huge interpolation in the Mahabharata, in the
>   genre known as 'wisdom literature.' The narrative progression is
>   placed on hold almost from the first page. Instead we get a long and
>   winding recapitulation of Brahmanic lore, including weighty treatises
>   on topics such as kingcraft, metaphysics, cosmology, geography, and
>   mythology. There are discussions of the Sankya and Yoga philosophical
>   schools, and mentions of Buddhism. It is apparent that the Santi Parva
>   was added to the Mahabharata at a later time than the main body of the
>   epic.

Is it possible? Because it is not normal that such sections suddenly talk of cosmology and philosophies in detail.

Comment: Btw who has authority to state whether Shanti Parva is interpolation or not?..

Comment: @Tezz the same authority based on which the translation has been made.

Comment: shanti parva is a dialogue between bhishma & yudhishtira.. where bhishma gives lot of advice to yudhishtir since he does not have peace even after winning the war. so what's the need for narrative (3rd person historical) progression ? also, i personally dont believe translations very much. the words of saints can only be understood by other saints or disciplined spiritualists. linguists can only read lines, while saints can read in between them to get true meaning.. for e.g yaksha prashnam - all answers given by yudhishtir seem ordinary but cryptic messages are hidden in each.

Comment: The Shanti Parva is definitely not an interpolation.  It's quoted by countless Acharyas and commentators, and forms an integral part of the Mahabharata.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan the less we talk of these acharyas the better it is.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi In this instance, problem is not with the acharyas but the interpolated scriptures were considered "the written law" by their gurus and the gurus' gurus etc. The [Monkeys and Ladder experiment](http://i.snag.gy/kdu77.jpg) explains this very well... :) BTW, I heard in a recent discourse where the learned speaker was saying how peacock and peahen mate using tears and not the natural way :P It's funny how some users are still spreading this false theory on this site also - see [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8390/2995).

Comment: @sv. That peacock theory is folklore like laxmana Rekha with scriptual basis, people have problem with indologists playing with Hindu scriptures, this irawati lady for one suffers from a bad case of confirmation bias like other atheist indologist.while there are small interpolation it's impossible to interpolate whole chapter, the earliest of writings and tradition have mention 100k verse of Mahabharata and 24k of ramayana, so Hindus belive in that and not what these indologists say.

Comment: Shouldn't this be off topic? it is talking about an author (translator?) but not hinduism or its scriptures or people involved in those scriptures.

Comment: FYI, this question is being discussed in this meta post: [Questions asking whether something is an interpolation are opinion based and not appropriate for this site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/questions-asking-whether-something-is-an-interpolation-are-opinion-based-and-not). Maybe you add your comments there to prevent closure.

Comment: @Anisha where is Lakshman rekha in valmiki

Answer (score 3):

Mahabharata contains 100 parvas which are further grouped into 18 major parvas

[Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01003.htm) gives list of 100 parvas which includes Santi as well:

> Then the coronation of the wise Yudhishthira. The next is called the 'Grihapravibhaga'. Then comes **'Santi'**, then 'Rajadharmanusasana', then 'Apaddharma', then 'Mokshadharma'. Those that follow are called respectively 'Suka-prasna-abhigamana', 'Brahma-prasnanusana', the origin of 'Durvasa', the disputations with Maya. The next is to be known as 'Anusasanika'.
>
> ...
>
> **The high-souled Vyasa composed these hundred parvas** ...

As you can see above that **these 100 parvas including Santi were composed by Vayasa**.

---

The same Adi Parva chapter describes Santi Parva:

> Twelfth in number cometh the Santi Parva, which increaseth the understanding and in which is related the despondency of Yudhishthira on his having slain his fathers, brothers, sons, maternal uncles and matrimonial relations. In this Parva is described how from his bed of arrows Bhishma expounded various systems of duties worth the study of kings desirous of knowledge; this Parva expounded the duties relative to emergencies, with full indications of time and reasons. By understanding these, a person attaineth to consummate knowledge. The mysteries also of final emancipation have been expatiated upon. This is the twelfth Parva the favourite of the wise. It consists of three hundred and thirty-nine sections, and contains fourteen thousand, seven hundred and thirty-two slokas.

Answer (score 3):

**Is Shanti Parva an interpolation?**

Mahabharata itself says that originally it had 24,000 verses exclusive of the episodes. Only later there was another compilation that extended it to 100,000 verses.

> Vyasa executed the compilation of the Bharata, **exclusive of the
> episodes originally in twenty-four thousand verses; and so much only
> is called by the learned as the Bharata.** ............. After that he
> executed another compilation, **consisting of ...one hundred thousand in
> the regions of mankind.**

**Mahabharata, Adi Parva, Section I** translated by Sri K. M. Ganguli

This pretty much states that the majority of the text we see today was a later addition. So while there may have been a Shanti Parva in the first version of Mahabharata (Shanti or peace must come after the 18-day war) there is no doubt that a lot of the material in the Shanti handed down to us is a later addition.

**Does all this matter? Does Hinduism depend on whether the Shanti or any other parva has interpolations? Does Bhishma speak only banalities in the Shanti?**

The answer is a firm no to all three. Mahabharata is not a source text of Hinduism. The Vedas and particularly the Upanishads are the source texts. The ten Upanishads commentated upon by Shankaracharya and the Upanishads mentioned by him in the commentary are accepted by scholars as authoritative.

> Upanishads are the most important sources of Vedanta philosophy. **The
> ten Upanishads on which Sankara (A.D. 788-820) wrote commentaries have
> been accepted as more ancient and authoritative.** Mandukyoupanishad,
> the smallest of these, has the unique distinction of being commentated
> upon by Gaudapada (7th cent. A.D.), the teacher of Govindapada (8th
> cent. A.D.) who was himself the teacher of Sankara.

**A concise encyclopedia of Hinduism** by Swami Harshananda

**What is the role of Mahabharata?**

> The wisdom of this work, like unto an instrument of applying
> collyrium, **hath opened the eyes of the inquisitive world blinded by
> the darkness of ignorance. As the sun dispelleth the darkness, so doth
> the Bharata by its discourses on religion, profit, pleasure and final
> release, dispel the ignorance of men. As the full-moon by its mild
> light expandeth the buds of the water-lily, so this Purana, by
> exposing the light of the Sruti hath expanded the human intellect. By
> the lamp of history, which destroyeth the darkness of ignorance, the
> whole mansion of nature is properly and completely illuminated.**

**Mahabharata Adi Parva Section I** translated by Sri K. M. Ganguli

Has Mahabharata lived up to its promise? I think the answer is yes. A short section of the Mahabharata, Gita, has reached the status of one of Prasthanatrayi in the Vedanta school.

Is the Shanti Parva banal as claimed by some scholars? I have given below an excerpt from Shanti.

> Bhishma said: Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in
> themselves they be fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious
> and wise. In days of old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth,
> which should remove all doubts, that **scriptures are no scriptures if
> they cannot stand the test of reason.**

**Mahabharat Shanti Parva Section CXLII** translated by Sri K. M. Ganguli

In my opinion the idea that scriptures must also satisfy the test of reason is a sensational statement and proves the scholars wrong who claim that the Shanti parva indulges in banalities. Is the truth value of the Shanti Parva wisdom diminished if scholars who claim that a mortally wounded Bhishma did not speak them are proved right? I would think the answer is a firm no.

Comment: 'Does all this matter? Does Hinduism depend on whether the Shanti or any other parva has interpolations? What is the role of Mahabharata?' - these are not part of OP's question. It was a simple yes/no question.

Comment: 'In my opinion the idea that scriptures must also satisfy the test of reason is a sensational statement and proves the scholars wrong who claim that the Shanti parva indulges in banalities.' - So, a single statement you find interesting disproves whatever is stated in the other 150+ chapters.

Comment: FYI, here's what Bhishma [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b005.htm) about women: "There is no creature more sinful, O son, than women. Woman is a blazing fire. She is the illusion, O king, that the Daitya Maya created. She is the sharp edge of the razor. She is poison. She is a snake. She is fire. She is, verily, all these united together....The Creator himself is incapable of restraining them within the limits that are proper: what need then be said of men?"

Comment: I  have already answered the question with a yes. I just wanted to say that interpolation does not reduce the importance of Shanti Parva. I have found many gems in Shanti. The idea that even scripture must satisfy  the test of reason is enough to make the Shanti Parva priceless. Let me give an example. The quote you have given about women is easy to understand given Bhishma's experience with women. We can use Bhishma's own advice that a scripture must satisfy the test of reason to reject his opinion about women.

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship that's not a very good analysis of that Parva even. For starters, Bhishma and even Yudhishthira aren't divine sources in my opinion these characters embody different social phenomena and characters within society. Bhishma praises women in that parva as well. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826371.html This has made me believe quite simply Bhishma isn't generalizing. He sees a set of women with bad Apsaric qualities and those with good qualities. Also, think of the backstory behind Bhishma as well.

Comment: From what I see in Bhishma's point of view women should be treated with respect, but he also warns Yudhishthira that women can also be manipulative as well. I see nothing wrong in bringing multiple natures of one gender. Men are often criticized for falling into this manipulation for their desires.

Answer (score 2):

If some one else also says that Shanti parva is an interpolation, that is hardly a proof for such speculative and unfounded statement. There are some speculations that entire Bhagavad-gita is an interpolation. To draw such conclusion one of the following three must be true -

1. There is difference in shaili (or style of writing)
2. It contradicts the concepts stated in this work itself.
3. It conflicts with other works of Vedavyasa.

None of these is true.

Bhishma did not prolong his death by six months, but only for about two months for him to go from Dakshinayana to Uttarayana. The war did not happen at the beginning of Dakshinayana, but almost end of dakShinayana. Also he did not die as soon as uttarAyana started. He waited for a good day which was “Magha Shukla AshTami”.

Keeping the vows itself is an accomplishment. That is not for accomplishing something else.

These simple facts indicate that the research was a bit sloppy.

To justify their irrational statements, some indologists and others tried to play the “Brahmana card”.

Bori’s critical edition team did enough research and their critical edition also contains Shantiparva. Also, In Adiparva, it lists all the parvas and there Shantiparva is also listed. It is not right to apply our rules of bearing the pain to Bhishma and talking about his age and concluding that such an old man could not bear that pain is not a strong argument at all, considering the kind of battle skills he exhibited.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Request you to kindly look at [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)

Comment: Compare the life of shuka deva for instance in bhagwatam and other puranas there are contradictions. To cover this up they say kalpa bheda excuse. Mahabharata was MADE UP to 1 lakh verses later on. In tatparya nirnaya you can see that madwacharya makes statements that ramayana and mbh have interpolation. Over the time with no press or printing it is very much a possibility.